Does spark shuffle/exchange converts compress data to uncompress form?
I have input dataset which is 450gb in s3 parquet compressed format. However during exchange it's showing 10 TB. is there any way to tune it. Tow large table are getting joined and and no other transformation.

Spark submit
spark-submit --conf spark.sql.files.maxPartitionBytes=268435456 \
--master yarn --deploy-mode cluster  --conf spark.yarn.maxAppAttempts=1 \
--conf spark.sql.adaptive.enabled=true --conf spark.dynamicAllocation.enabled=false \
--conf spark.sql.parquet.filterPushdown=true \
--conf spark.sql.adaptive.coalescePartitions.enabled=true \
--conf spark.sql.adaptive.advisoryPartitionSizeInBytes=268435456 \
--conf spark.sql.adaptive.optimizeSkewsInRebalancePartitions.enabled=true \
--conf spark.sql.adaptive.rebalancePartitionsSmallPartitionFactor=.5 \
--conf spark.sql.adaptive.coalescePartitions.parallelismFirst=false \
--conf spark.sql.adaptive.coalescePartitions.initialPartitionNum=12000 \
--conf spark.sql.adaptive.localShuffleReader.enabled=true \
--conf spark.shuffle.io.connectionTimeout=8000 \
--conf spark.network.timeout=50000s  --conf spark.files.fetchTimeout=600s \
--conf spark.serializer=org.apache.spark.serializer.KryoSerializer --conf spark.kryoserializer.buffer.max=1g \
--conf spark.memory.storageFraction=0.05 --conf spark.memory.fraction=.8 \
--conf spark.shuffle.compress=true --conf spark.shuffle.spill.compress=true \
--conf spark.hadoop.fs.s3.multipart.th.fraction.parts.completed=0.99 \
--conf spark.sql.objectHashAggregate.sortBased.fallbackThreshold=4000000 \
--conf spark.reducer.maxReqsInFlight=12 \
--conf spark.shuffle.io.retryWait=60s \
--conf spark.shuffle.io.maxRetries=10 \
--conf spark.reducer.maxSizeInFlight=256m \
--conf spark.reducer.maxBlocksInFlightPerAddress=100 \
--conf spark.io.compression.codec=zstd \
--conf spark.shuffle.service.enabled=true \
--conf spark.io.compression.zstd.level=3 \
--conf spark.executor.cores=5 \
--conf spark.executor.instances=1200 \
--conf spark.executor.memory=34g --conf spark.driver.memory=60g --conf spark.executor.memoryOverhead=5g --conf spark.driver.memoryOverhead=4g \
--conf spark.hadoop.fs.s3a.fast.output.enabled=true \
--conf spark.executor.extraJavaOptions="-XX:+UseG1GC -XX:+UnlockDiagnosticVMOptions -XX:+G1SummarizeConcMark -XX:InitiatingHeapOccupancyPercent=35 -verbose:gc -XX:+PrintGCDetails -XX:+PrintGCDateStamps -XX:OnOutOfMemoryError='kill -9 %p' -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore=/home/hadoop/.config/certs/InternalAndExternalTrustStore.jks" --conf spark.driver.extraJavaOptions="-XX:+UseG1GC " \
test.py


This is a good explanation: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74784531/understanding-the-shuffle-in-spark
